# MySQL stored procedure: how to shorten the statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Just want to ask your help regarding creation of a stored procedure in MySQL database. This is my first time in creating a stored procedure.

Most likely, I used to creation views but this time, I need to implement a stored procedure in the mysql database. I have here created a simple one but I think it's redundant in statement. Is there anyone who can help me shorten the statement?

With this, it can help me to study more regarding stored procedure. Please see code for reference. Much appreciated with your help.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `doris_master_data`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `webserver_service_order`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `webserver_service_order`(
IN xselection BIGINT(8),
IN xreceived_from_date BIGINT(8),
IN xreceived_to_date BIGINT(8))
BEGIN

IF xselection=0 THEN

SELECT DISTINCT
so.service_code,
sl.service_name,
xx.Total_Services
FROM 
service_order so
INNER JOIN services_lists sl ON so.service_code=sl.service_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
    a.service_code,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(a.service_code,'-',a.service_order_code)) AS Total_Services
    FROM
    service_order a
    WHERE
    (a.service_order_date_received BETWEEN xreceived_from_date AND xreceived_to_date)
    AND a.service_code_is_active=1
    AND a.requirement_code_is_active=1
    GROUP BY a.service_code
) AS xx ON so.service_code=xx.service_code
WHERE
(so.service_order_date_received BETWEEN xreceived_from_date AND xreceived_to_date)
AND so.service_code_is_active=1
AND so.requirement_code_is_active=1;

ELSE
SELECT DISTINCT
so.service_code,
sl.service_name,
xx.Total_Services
FROM 
service_order so
INNER JOIN services_lists sl ON so.service_code=sl.service_code
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
    a.service_code,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(a.service_code,'-',a.service_order_code)) AS Total_Services
    FROM
    service_order a
    WHERE
    (a.service_order_date_received BETWEEN xreceived_from_date AND xreceived_to_date)
    AND a.service_code_is_active=1
    AND a.requirement_code_is_active=1
    GROUP BY a.service_code
) AS xx ON so.service_code=xx.service_code
WHERE
so.service_code=xselection AND
(so.service_order_date_received BETWEEN xreceived_from_date AND xreceived_to_date)
AND so.service_code_is_active=1
AND so.requirement_code_is_active=1;

END IF;


END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: *"MySQL Stored Procedure How to Shorten the Statement"* i assume the code works? if so this question is offtopic here and should be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No problem but mine name is Raymond not Raymund ..